# Reflexive transitive closure = (zero or more) Kleene star?

Tags: terminology, closure-properties, kleene-star, transitivity

In [Alloy Tutorial](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/frame-FS-1.html) they denote some reflexive transitive closure with Kleene star saying that they admit zero or more elements at that position.

```
  // File system is connected
  fact {
    FSObject in Root.*contents
  }
```

> In Alloy, in can be read as "subset of" (among other things). The operator "*" denotes reflexive transitive closure. Thus, this fact says that the set of all file system objects is a subset of everything reachable from the Root by following the contents relation zero or more times.

[Reflexive Transitive Closure *](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/sidenote-rtc.html)

> In Alloy, "*bar" denoted the reflexive transitive closure of bar. It is equavalent to (iden + ^bar) where ^ is the (non-reflexive) transitive closure operator.

Can you explain the closure and star operators such thut it becomes obvious that they are identical?

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I'm not 100% sure about the Alloy syntax since I never used it -- what follows is accurate on the general principles but the syntax could be slightly different)

Basically, `S.*bar` means starting from `S` and using `.bar` any number $n\geq 0$ of times.

Instead, `S.^bar` means starting from `S` and using `.bar` any positive number $n > 0$ of times.

It is immediate to see that `S.^bar` is equivalent to `S.bar.*bar` since the latter denotes zero or more steps after a first step, hence one or more steps.

If the language allows `S.iden` to mean "zero steps from `S`", and `+` to denote union, then we can also write `S.^bar` as `S.(iden + ^bar)` which can be read as "zero steps or (one step or more)" which is the same thing as "zero or more steps".

---

In the underlying theory, one can define the reflexive and transitive closure of a relation $R \in \mathcal{P}(A\times A)$ as the smallest relation $R^* \in \mathcal{P}(A\times A)$ satisfying

$$
R^* = I_A \cup R \circ R^*
$$

where $I_A$ stands for the identity relation. The existence of the smallest $R^*$ is guaranteed by the Tarski fixed point theorem (on the complete lattice of the relations). According to the Kleene fixed point theorem (and a few minor simplifications) one can also write it as
$$
R^* = \bigcup_{n\geq 0} R^n
$$
where $R^n$ denoted the self-composition of $R$ for $n$ times.

Comment: In $R^* = I_A \cup R \circ R^*$, do you define the relation in terms of itself? Is your purpose is to show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} R^n = I_A \cup R \circ R^*$? Can you reduce it into more layman terms?

Comment: @LittleAlien I corrected the first part: it is indeed zero or more. For the latter part, if you want to be informal, you can pretend that $R^*$ is defined in terms of itself as $I \cup R\circ R^*$ (or pretend that the definition is recursive). The truth is the equation $R^* = I \cup R\circ R^*$ might have multiple solutions for $R^*$, and we take the smallest one. The underlying theory is quite broad (you can look up fixed point theorems or domain theory), and I can't summarize it here. However, $R^* = \bigcup_n R^N$ provide its smallest solution in a convenient form, in layman terms.

Comment: @LittleAlien From $R^* = \bigcup_{n\geq 0} R^n = I \cup R \cup R\circ R\ \cup \cdots$ you can see that the solution is indeed "zero or more times" $R$.